# NSStatusItem (cocoa) location on screen

Tags: cocoa, nsstatusitem

I am trying to get the on screen location of an NSStatusItem so that I can perform a click on that area via code like below. I am doing this so that my users can press a hotkey to see the menu.

```
event = CGEventCreateMouseEvent(NULL, kCGEventLeftMouseDown, newLocation, kCGMouseButtonLeft);
CGEventPost(kCGHIDEventTap, event);
CFRelease(event);
```

Does anyone know of a way to get the location?, I have been trying ideas and searching for days and have found several ideas but none of them seem to work in leopard/snow leopard

The NSStatusItem is using an NSMenu not a custom view.

Comment: There's nothing public for that, and it probably shouldn't be done in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

Don't do this by simulating a mouse event, that is completely the wrong way to go.

You can use the `-popUpStatusItemMenu:` method of `NSStatusItem` to show the menu. You can call this method from a hot key by using a `CGEventTap` to capture global events that your `NSStatusItem` can respond to.

On 10.6 you can use the `+addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:handler:` method of `NSEvent` to capture global events instead of using `CGEventTap` directly.

Comment: Thanks for answering, I am using popUpStatusItemMenu: already but the only downside is that it doesn't highlight the nsstatusitem so I was trying to find an alternative. I think I will just have to settle for popUpStatusItemMenu

Comment: `addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:handler:` is for monitoring for events, not posting them, which is what he's doing with the event tap in the question's example. Moreover, it's not the easiest way to implement a hotkey; that would be Carbon Event Manager, whose hotkey API is still supported (even in 64-bit).

Answer (score 0):

Thinking out loud you could create your own custom view for the NSStatusItem. Then for example from the AppController:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {    
float width = 30.0;
float height = [[NSStatusBar systemStatusBar] thickness];
NSRect viewFrame = NSMakeRect(0, 0, width, height);
statusItem = [[[NSStatusBar systemStatusBar] statusItemWithLength:width] retain];
[statusItem setView:[[[MyCustomView alloc] initWithFrame:viewFrame controller:self] autorelease]];
```

And to simulate the highlight you'd send a message to your custom view. Then when drawing MyCustomView:

```
// In MyCustomView.m
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)rect {
if (clicked) {
    [[NSColor selectedMenuItemColor] set];
    NSRectFill(rect);
}
```

As well as using `-popUpStatusItemMenu:`.